# WCS 1.1.1 OGC Complaint Test Failed in Team Engine

Tags: geoserver, ogc, wcs, testing, compliance

I have been testing my GeoServer 2.12.1 for OGC Compliant to WCS 1.1.1 Standard. But I got following errors while testing with the OGC Team Engine.

How do I resolve the issues?

1. **wcs:GetCoverage_RangeSubset_InterpolationMethod_Missing - Failed**

> Request d1e19427_1:    Method: POST    URL:
>   http://BASEURL/geoserver/wcs?    Body:

```
<GetCoverage xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
             xmlns:ows11="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:ctl="http://www.occamlab.com/ctl"
             xmlns:ctlp="http://www.occamlab.com/te/parsers"
             xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions"
             xmlns:gen="java:com.occamlab.te.Generator"
             xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
             xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
             xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
             xmlns:te="http://www.occamlab.com/te"
             xmlns:tec="java:com.occamlab.te.TECore"
             xmlns:tems="java:com.occamlab.te.web.MonitorServlet"
             xmlns:tep="http://teamengine.sourceforge.net/parsers"
             xmlns:wcs="http://schemas.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1"
             xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
             xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             service="WCS"
             version="1.1.1"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1 http://schemas.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1/wcsAll.xsd">
   <ows11:Identifier>topp:rotated</ows11:Identifier>
   <DomainSubset>
      <ows11:BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84">
         <ows11:LowerCorner>7.7634301664746515 45.14713380418506</ows11:LowerCorner>
         <ows11:UpperCorner>7.764350661575157 45.14763319238466</ows11:UpperCorner>
      </ows11:BoundingBox>
   </DomainSubset>
   <RangeSubset>
      <FieldSubset>
         <ows11:Identifier>contents</ows11:Identifier>
         <InterpolationType/>
      </FieldSubset>
   </RangeSubset>
   <Output format="image/tiff"/>
</GetCoverage>
```

> Error in call to extension function {public org.w3c.dom.NodeList
>   com.occamlab.te.TECore.request(org.w3c.dom.Document,java.lang.String)
>   throws java.lang.Throwable}: Exception in extension function
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Result: Failed

2. **wcs:GetCoverage_Store_Bogus - Failed**

> Request d1e24800_1:    Method: GET    URL:
>   http://BASEURL/geoserver/wcs?&service=WCS&request=GetCoverage&version=1.1.1&identifier=topp:rotated&BoundingBox=7.7634301664746515,45.14713380418506,7.764350661575157,45.14763319238466,urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84&Format=image/tiff&Store=bogus
>   Error in call to extension function {public org.w3c.dom.NodeList
>   com.occamlab.te.TECore.request(org.w3c.dom.Document,java.lang.String)
>   throws java.lang.Throwable}: Exception in extension function
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
>   Result: Failed

I have changed the input for bogus to various values but still not working. The procedure followed for testing the WCS is from http://docs.geoserver.org/2.12.1/developer/cite-test-guide/index.html#run-wcs-1-1-tests.

Also, the WCS Capabilties base URL to be entered for testing the WCS Compliance as mentioned in the post https://github.com/opengeospatial/ets-wps10/issues/9#issuecomment-253070197.

Answer (score 1):

This (and your other questions) are hard to answer without knowing a lot more about your set up and configuration of GeoServer. If you check the [GeoServer build server](https://build.geoserver.org/view/testing-cite/) you will see that the CITE tests are run each day and are all currently passing so this is probably a local issue.

Also, is there some pressing reason to run the CITE tests yourself?

Comment: I did a fresh setup of GeoServer 2.12.1 in my Linux Machine and need to know whether the GeoServer is OGC Compliant to all open standards. The GeoServer Data Directory has been pointed to the respective data directory (cite-wms, cite-wfs, cite-wcs...) from the geoserver github https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/master/data and tested in team engine.

Comment: It is however to be noticed that the CITE tests run there are a fixed version from 2013, the project did not have the resources to keep up with the continuous changes in the tests themselves (and the bugs that sometimes would creep in the test itself). Funding welcomed. See also https://git.osgeo.org/gitea/osgeo/todo/issues/25